# How to remove the apache2 page from url in the website

Tags: amazon-ec2

My website site is setup in ec2 instance (linux ami).
For a last week my website couldn't open. I see a apache2 page on my website url.
If anyone have any solution of this so please help me....

Thanks...

Comment: Is this page an error page by chance? If so, what error is it giving you? If not, what content is it giving you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done setup the virtual host for your web app ?

If yes, can you look at logs file, usually located on /var/log/httpd  :

> tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log
>
> tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log

If no, you can look at this [guide](https://nouveauframework.org/blog/vhosts-running-multiple-sites-on-a-single-aws-ec2-instance/)